# finding the sum of the CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.6

Write a function named "csv_sum" that takes a string as a parameter representing the name of a CSV file with 5 columns in the format ",,,," and returns the sum of all the values in the fifth column from the input file

```
import csv
def csv_sum(st):
    val=0
    with open(st)as a:
        reader=csv.reader(a)
        for line in reader:
            for b in line:
                val=val+int(line[4])
    return val
```

I don't fully understand how to use CSV files so what I have above is my attempt at solving it. But I am getting an error on input['animal.csv']

Example...

animal.csv

```
9,16,136,-24,3

3,13,170,-21,4
```

returned: 35

expected: 7

Comment: What's up with the `for b in line:`:? 3x5 + 4x5 = 35, you're adding the last value once for each value on the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're unnecessarily iterating through each column in a row when you only need the 5th column. Remove the `for b in line` statement and your code should work:

```
def csv_sum(st):
    val=0
    with open(st)as a:
        reader=csv.reader(a)
        for line in reader:
            val=val+int(line[4])
    return val
```